# Move all but the five latest files to new directory

Tags: linux, bash, unix

There is an hypotetical process that is creating a series of zip files in volumeA.

The process is a multithreaded process and is writing 5 zip files at a time.

You are running out of space on volumeA, craft a script that will move all but the 
5 latest written zip files from volumeA to volumeB

Comment: I managed to get the five newest files no problem:

`#!/bin/bash
FILES=$(ls -tr | tail -n 5)
new_dir=$1
if [ $new_dir !=="" ]; then
        printf "%s\n" "${FILES[@]}"

        for i in "${FILES[@]}"
        do
                mv $i $new_dir
        done
else
        echo "Please provide a directory you wish to move the files to";
fi`

Comment: Craft a script - homework lingo. SHow some work before we can help u.

Answer (score 1):

This looks a little like homework, but could be fun. Let's see... Tools that might come in handy:

- ls -t (list, sorted by modification date, newest on top?)
- sort (?)
- cp (duh!)

OK, so here is a plan:

- ls -t | SKIP 5 | xargs cp ...

You will need to figure out how to skip the first 5 lines and continue with the rest. The rest will then be piped to xargs, which will call cp for each input line.

How to implement SKIP? Let's google "linux skip first n lines": http://knol.google.com/k/justin-crites/skip-first-line-of-input-on-gnu-linux/r0h4brikem0y/5#

OK, that was easy:

- ls -t | sed 1,5d | xargs cp ...

Next: How does that crummy xargs work again? I never really get around to looking at that...

... luckily, we have a whole *internet* to look through. So, your script might look like this:

```
ls -t | sed 1,5d | xargs -i 1 mv volumeA/'{}' volumeB/'{}'
```

Comment: `sed 1,5d` can be replaced by `tail -n +6`.

Comment: @jfgagne: thanks. I did check tail, but it seemed to only do, well, tailing. anyway, this is a homework question that I just decided to solve because I needed something to get me out of an afternoon digestion low ;)

Answer (score 1):

I can't do your homework for you but I can tell you that you use a combination of the `ls` and `head` commands to get the list zip files that you need - ie. all but the most recent 5.

See the `man` pages for `ls` and `head`, ie:

```
# man ls
# man head
```